# How to type value of `fetch().then()` response argument in reactjs typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fetch-api

I am trying to get a JSON from response of the fetch function, however I fail to do so in 1 `then` call. Take a look at this example:

```
fetch(fetchURL)
    .then(
        response => {
            const json = response.json();
            const payload = json.data as MyJsonObject[]; // TS2339 error
            return dispatch(anotherAction(payload));
        },
        error => console.log('An error occurred.', error)
    )
```

If I try to access `data` property of my `json` variable I get TS2339 error: `Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Promise<Any>'`. However if I try to access it in subsequent `then` calls, it resolves fine, as in this snippet:

```
fetch(fetchURL)
    .then(
        response => {
            return response.json();
        },
        error => console.log('An error occurred.', error)
    )
    .then(
        json => {
            const payload = json.data as MyJsonObject[]; // All good, no TS2339 error
            return dispatch(anotherAction(payload));
        }
    )
```

I am puzzled by the fact that it does resolve in 2nd `fetch` call but not in the 1st one and I would very much appreciate if anyone could elucidate the reason for such behaviour and how can one handle it properly? Because as of now 2nd `then` call would be executed even if there is an error in the 1st one and solving it with boolean flags does not feel like the most optimal solution, I would like to keep it in just 1 `then` call.

Comment: `response.json()` returns a promise. You need to wait for it to resolve.

Comment: Side note: `.then( json => { const json = response.json();` you accept `json` as parameter but then use `response` as if it's defined.

Comment: @tkausl, oh I see. Thanks.

Comment: @VLAZ, thanks for spotting this. My mistake of copy-pasting. I have made the necessary edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The response of a fetch() request is a Stream object, which means that when we call the json() method, a Promise is returned since the reading of the stream will happen asynchronously.

[From](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch?hl=en)

which means you can do either:

```
fetch(fetchURL)
    .then(
        response => {
            const json = response.json().then(
              const payload = json.data as MyJsonObject[]; // TS2339 error
              return dispatch(anotherAction(payload));
            );
        },
        error => console.log('An error occurred.', error)
    )
```

Or the chained `then` you included in your question

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Sultan H.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57250816/3805929)'s answer, here is the solution with appropriate syntax:

```
fetch(fetchURL)
    .then(
        response => {
            response.json().then(
                json => {
                    const payload = json.data as MyJsonObject[];
                    return dispatch(anotherAction(payload));
                }
            );
        },
        error => console.log('An error occurred.', error)
    );
```